# Allow User Input to Just Fractions and Integers (but Not Mixed Numbers) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Just as the question states above, how could I limit user input to just fractions (mixed numbers not included), and integers? Examples being 3/4 or -5, but not -3 4/5.

I also want the program to limit characters to integers and fractions. So I don't want extra characters allowed like spaces or letters.

I believe there may be a way to do this with regular expressions, which would be an answer I'd prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this filter:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/^(-?(?:\d+(?:\/\d*)?)?).*$/, '$1')" />
</form>
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of input
- `(` - start of capture group
- `-?` - expect optional `-` at the start
- `(?:` - start of non-capture group

  - `\d+` - expect 1+ digits
  - `(?:` - start of non-capture group

    - `\/\d*` - expect a slash and optional digits
  - `)?` - end of non-capture group, `?` makes it optional
- `)?` - end of non-capture group, `?` makes it optional
- `)` - end of capture group
- `.*` - everything that's left
- `$` - end of input
- reference capture group with `'$1'` in replacement

Comment: This works. Thanks. Although you can't put two negatives numbers with a fraction in between, but that would just simplify to a positive fraction.

Comment: YW. Well, I addressed your description and the examples you gave.

Comment: `/^(-?(?:\d+(?:\/-?\d*)?)?).*$/` I believe would be what is above and if you wanted a negative number divided by a negative number. If I am wrong about that please correct me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `[-]?[0-9]*[\/]?[0-9]+`, then leverage the `pattern` attribute in `input`:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="whatever" pattern="[-]?[0-9]*[\/]?[0-9]+" oninput="this.reportValidity()" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. The only thing that I would want would be instead of the pattern attribute, have an oninput value then replace the characters I don't want with nothing, and allow the characters you specified in the regex code. In summarization, not allowing the characters in the textbox at all instead of an error that allows the character input.

Comment: @BillJoe I'll see what I can do, but that deviates far from just simple regex.

Comment: A good start to this would be `<input type="text" name="whatever" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^-0-9\/]/g, '')"/>` Where it doesn't allow anything but numbers, a negative, or forward slash.

Comment: @BillJoe OK. Why don't you use it then?

Comment: Because it's not done. I am able to allow double dashes, double slashes and etc. I'm still working on all the things that aren't allowed. If I find an answer, I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in JavaScript, check if the line is only integers, or the line is only fractions, if not, replace the input with the fractions that are found. If you need any different behavior just change the inputValidator function.

The input is validated onblur, you have to remove the mouse from the input box and click outside.

```js
const allIntegers = /^(?:[+-]?\d+(?: |$))+$/;
const allFractions = /^(?:[+-]?\d+\/\d+(?: |$))+$/;

function inputValidator(obj) {
  const text = obj.value;
  if(!allIntegers.test(text)&&!allFractions.test(text)){
    alert("Not Ok!");
    obj.value = (text.match(/[+-]?\d+\/\d+/g)||[]).join(" ");
  } else{
    alert("Ok");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="my_form" type="text" name="My Form" onblur="inputValidator(this)" />
</form>
```